# Erro em ": base" indica um token inesperado

Tags: c#, .net, herança, construtor, token

Está dando erro na linha 24 (indicada abaixo), diz ": token inesperado". O que fazer para resolver?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Exercicio3{
        public Exercicio3(){
            Console.WriteLine("a");
        }
        public Exercicio3(string pa){
            Console.WriteLine(pa + "\nh");
        }
    }
         class ClasseMae : Exercicio3{
        public ClasseMae(){
            Console.WriteLine("c");
        }
        public void Exercicio3(string pa)
  linha 24   :base(pa){
            Console.WriteLine(pa + "\nd");
        }
         }
             
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             Exercicio3 exercicio = new Exerccio3("e");
            ClasseMae mae = new ClasseMae("b");
            Console.Read();
        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Essa linha não faz sentido. E na verdade nem sei qual seria certa. Programar é em primeiro lugar ter requisitos claros. Não tem isso na pergunta, então qualquer resposta terá que chutar qual é a solução. Não existe solução de problema quando não se sabe qual é o problema.

Vou entender que queria criar um construtor ali, então a sintaxe está errada por duas razões: a primeira é que tem um tipo de retorno, e construtores não tem isso; e a segunda é que o nome do construtor deve ser o nome da classe.

Se não é isso, também não poderia usar o nome de outra classe, mas ao mesmo tempo nem faria sentido.

O erro é estranho porque acerta em um construtor e não no outro.

De fato tudo isso não faz sentido. Programar orientado a objeto, criar classes precisa fazer sentido, precisa resolver um problema. Escrever um código por escrever sem que ele demonstre o problema não ensina nada útil. Esse exemplo é isso, ele não ensina criar classes, a não ser pela sintaxe de como cria uma classe e uma herança. Ela não ensina programar, não ensina fazer algo real, algo que crie um entendimento. Treinar o erro faz a pessoa errar a vida inteira.

Fora isso a sintaxe usada é bem antiga e sem cuidado. Se está usando algum material, jogue fora. Parece que está decorando coisas em vez de aprender o que elas significam, isso não dá certo. O código como dever ser (preste atenção em todos detalhes, embora eu não tenha mudado tudo o que poderia):

```
using static System.Console;

public class Exercicio3 {
    public Exercicio3() => WriteLine("a");
    public Exercicio3(string pa) => WriteLine(pa + "\nh");
}
public class ClasseMae : Exercicio3 {
    public ClasseMae() => WriteLine("c");
    public ClasseMae(string pa) : base(pa) => WriteLine(pa + "\nd");
}
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Exercicio3 exercicio = new("e");
        ClasseMae mae = new("b");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nzUbnw). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/ConstructorSignature.cs).

Mas isso não é um bom código, mesmo funcionando e tendo uma sintaxe mais adequada. Códigos bons fazem sentido, não apenas são textos jogados que compilam.

Comment: ok. desculpe e obrigado pelo empenho em ajudar.